# How do we stop analyzing tokens in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

so I have a field like this in my elasticsearch index:

```
"filename": { "type": "text", "fielddata": true }
```

I am trying to use the Java API to query it like so:

```
client.prepareSearch(IMYINDEX).setQuery(query)
            .addDocValueField("filename")
```

However, the field comes back with this kind of situation:

```
"fields": { "filename": ["bob4322_35_223", "jpg"] }
```

I use `SearchHitField` to grab the object. Now I could loop through and recombine the tokens to be : `"bob4322_35_223.jpg"`

However, then I am guessing the standard_analyzer is just removing the dot.

I want the full keyword of it which I don't see in _mapping.

I want the actual `"bob4322_35_223.jpg"`  ... It looks like standard_analyzer will get rid of "." and sometimes won't even properly analyze "-" (sometimes the array is missing parts of the dash e.g. `bob-45-joe-44-amy-12.jpg` becomes `[12, "jpg"]`)

Is there a way to disable analyzer while making this query? I don't need it in tokenized version. How do you do this?

I do not want to reingest the data as keyword or anything like that. I don't know if it would be efficient to pull in _sourceMap instead?

Comment: You need to set it as a keyword type field while mapping if you do not want it to be analyzed

Comment: So it looks like it was ingested as "type": "text". I don't want to reingest or redo it. Is there a way i can disable analyzer/token for now? Or is it easier to just fetch _source?

Comment: Can you post the mapping? There possibly is a filename.keyword if you let elasticsearch infer the mapping. Yes you can use source filtering to return the filename field text as well.

Comment: Usually I see "type: text" then "type: keyword" SUBFIELD, but in this situation I don't see that in _mapping. So it must be missing keyword subfield right? Or do all text fields HAVE a sub-keyword-field?